# How to determine and set the degree of parallelism in an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing

Is there a theory or clue to set the degree of parallelism in an Oracle query? For example:

`select * from some_table;`

If I want to run it in parallel, I can write it like below which set the parallel degree 10:

`select /*+parallel(10) */ * from some_table;`

the degree number can be changed to any other number. If you check the explain plan, you found the higher the degree of parallelism, the lower the cost.  My question is how to find a optimum degree number when you are writing the query and is there a theory or clue to set the degree of parallelism in an Oracle query?

Comment: If the table is small, then setting parallelism isn't going to help.  Consequently, the setting is going to require some judgement based on the size of the table (number of rows, size of each row), and the layout of the data on disk (I'm not sure how much control you get over that), and the hardware you're running on (setting parallelism to 64 on a 4-core machine probably won't help any; and lots of parallelism on a machine with a single disk drive may not help very much either).  These factors (and probably others I've not thought of) make it very hard to provide a good answer.

Comment: To extend Jonathan's comment the size of the row is a factor in the number of rows per block. You don't want 2 processes updating the same block if you can avoid it.

Comment: If you just use `/* parallel */` Oracle will try to find an optimal degree balancing all parameters and concurrent queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many variables affect the optimal setting, but Oracle can decide for itself, taking all the important factors into account itself. You do this by specify a parallel degree of auto, e.g. /*+ PARALLEL(auto) */ . The most difficult thing to predict when deciding this is the amount of load on the system at the time the query is run - what else is competing for the resources. What works at 11pm might be dreadfully slow and degrade system (not just query) performance at 11am. It would be well worth your while to read this:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm#CIHGJFFH

In particular, the section on "Degree of Parallelism".